# Are unique custom validators names required?

Tags: sails.js

When I run attempt to create a new Address, the validation fails each time, because of the custom validator. It still fails when I replace companyExists contents with 'return true'. I found that a workaround was to rename the custom validator in one of the files to something else such as companyExists2. It appears that custom validators cannot have the same name. Is this expected behavior for Sails.js? Postman returns a 400 error saying that the validation failed with a JSON response of:

```
"invalidAttributes": {
    "company": [
    {
        "rule": "companyExists",
        "message": "\"companyExists\" validation rule failed for input: 1\nSpecifically, it threw an error.  Details:\n undefined"
      }
    ]
 },
```

In models/Address.js I have:

```
module.exports = {
    attributes: {
        street: {
            type: 'string'
        },
        // More attributes
        company: {
            model: 'company',
            required: true,
            unique: true,
            companyExists: true
        }
    },
    types: {
        companyExists: function(companyID) {
            Company.findOne(companyID).exec(function(err, company) {
                if (err || !company) return false;
                return true;
            });
        }
    }
};
```

In models/Company.js I have:

```
module.exports = {
    attributes: {
        name: {
            type: 'string',
            required: true
        },
        // More attributes
        company: {
            model: 'company',
            required: true,
            unique: true,
            companyExists: true
       }
    },

    types: {
        companyExists: function(companyID) {
            Company.findOne(companyID, function (err, company) {
                if (err || !company) return false;
                return true;
            });
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Custom validation rules are merged with the built-in ones. That makes them accessible in all your models. If you need the same rule multiple times, you only have to write it once (doesn't matter in which model).

You also have to be careful not to collide with the existing rules. You can find the full list [here](http://sailsjs.org/documentation/concepts/models-and-orm/validations)